# Any ideas about an auto complete feature for iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, autosuggest

Can anyone point me to any example projects or tips on how to create an autocompleting textfield where the user types a common name, example "American Airlines" which has another value such as "AA" (for american airlines) and as the user types it suggests results based on whats in the the textfield?

Something like this:[image: example]

Any tips would be amazing!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[First get this source code](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField)

In my Experience Add a Search Display Controller in IB. Then I added code to RootViewController.m as follows:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
 NSInteger searchOption = controller.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex;
 return [self searchDisplayController:controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:searchString searchScope:searchOption];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
 NSString* searchString = controller.searchBar.text;
 return [self searchDisplayController:controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:searchString searchScope:searchOption];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString searchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {

 NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
 if ([searchString length])
  if (searchOption == 0) // full text, in my implementation.  Other scope button titles are "Author", "Title"
   predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@ OR author contains[cd] %@", searchString, searchString];
  else
   // docs say keys are case insensitive, but apparently not so.
   predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", [[controller.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles objectAtIndex:searchOption] lowercaseString], searchString];
 [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  abort();
    }           

 return YES;
}
```

[This is tutorial for help you.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values)

[And also get demo project.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848)

**Thanks. :)**

Comment: UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UISearchDisplayDelegate is also deprecated.) To manage the presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and later, instead use UISearchController

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my implementation, [MLPAutoCompleteTextField](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mlpautocompletetextfield). It's open source.

It does autocomplete similar to Google's instant search. It uses a [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to sort entries.

Comment: Is it possible to pull the suggestions from an entity i.e. table in core data, i.e. you have email addresses listed in core data, and you pull them based on what you are typing

Answer (score 0):

See my demo-project:

http://olegh.cc.st/autocomplete.html

Try to search "York" in the field "City", or "book" in the field "Domains"

Is this  what do you looking for?