# How to programmatically customize the text on iPhone's autocorrect bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, search, keyboard

I want to put an Android-Style autocorrect bar in my app, but I don't even know how to start.

The following link has a picture of what I want:
http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/how-to/how-to-enable-hidden-ios-5-auto-correct-bar-on-your-iphone/

Here are my questions:

**1)** How to programmatically enable it in objective-C?

**2)** How to customize the text on the bar according to what the user is typing? For example, if you start typing "Ma", I will suggest words in my own words database; i.e "Mango" first, "Manucure" second, etc.

How is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Follow this SO question[Any ideas about an auto complete feature for iOS development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785209/any-ideas-about-an-auto-complete-feature-for-ios-development)

you can customise the view to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Mayank, but I would actually prefer to use the autocorrect bar, because I'm asking the user to enter text into an UIAlertView, so I can't put a suggestion list under the alert view… The autocorrect bar would work with my Alert view.